# Where Is Carberautor Located On Mower?

Tags: lawn-mower

I have the TB110 11A-A23O711 (Troy Bilt) lawnmower and purchased some Gumout Starter Spray to try to get the mower to start.

It says I am supposed to spray this into the carberautor in order to use it, but where is my carberautor?

This is what I purchased... https://www.homedepot.com/p/Gumout-11-oz-Starting-Fluid-5072866/204802514?cm_mmc=ecc-_-THD_THANKYOU__V1_M1_CA-_-Product_URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look on the left hand side, in front of the gas filler.  There's a black plastic cover, about 4"x6".  That's the air filter.  The carburetor is right behind that.  Here, I think:

[image]

Comment: To use the spray I would remove the air filter, then spray inside the small circular hole that is behind the air filter?

Comment: Yes.  Just make sure the filter & cover are in place before you try to start it.  Sometimes there's a small blowback though the carb when it tries ti fire.